# tinyMCE is not defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I using TinyMCE in ASP.NET MVC 3 but I think this is not a problem.

Error:

jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined

localhost:67678/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js

```
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "simple"
    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->
<h3>
    Simple theme example</h3>
<p>
    This page shows you the simple theme and it's core functionality you can extend
    it by changing the code use the advanced theme if you need to configure/add more
    buttons etc. There are more examples on how to use TinyMCE in the <a href="http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/">
        Wiki</a>.
</p>
<!-- Gets replaced with TinyMCE, remember HTML in a textarea should be encoded -->
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
        &lt;p&gt;
            This is some example text that you can edit inside the &lt;strong&gt;TinyMCE editor&lt;/strong&gt;.
        &lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;
        Nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. Nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. Quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. Donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. Nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. Aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. Nunc interdum viverra sodales. Morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. Quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. Duis elementum congue ultrices. Cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. Fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. Integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. Morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros.
        &lt;/p&gt;
    </textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.location.protocol == 'file:') {
        alert("The examples might not work properly on the local file system due to security settings in your browser. Please use a real webserver.");
    }
</script>
```

Image:
[image]

fixed:

this is working

../../Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js

my question is why this does not work? and why VS 2010 doesn`t show error with path?

~/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js

Comment: this looks wierd indeed

Comment: @Thariama You know in my opinion it is look correct but why doesn`t work? I don`t know.

Comment: did you verify that this is the correct path for tinymce: "~/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"

Comment: @Thariama VS 2010 show me this is correct path (as you can see in image I haven`t got underlined path). maybe you have got link to project I can test it.

Comment: Any clue why does it say: "jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3" and why is your url is localhost:67678/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js ?

Comment: @Dima you know I changed number of my localhost (this is not a problem) have you got idea how to fix it?

Comment: i am not using asp.net so i cannot help much here. the reason for your problem is that the path is wrong at some place - but i can only guess where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct Answer -> ../../Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js